# FireFox's NoScript equivalent for IE 11 in Windows 8.1

Tags: firefox, script, internet-explorer, blocking, noscript

For my IE 11 in Windows 8, I need a tool I can use to disable/enable JavaScripts on various web pages dynamically when I open a web page - something similar to what the NoScript plugin for FireFox does. However, I cannot find a good tool for that. It seems, we can only disable scripting for all/some sites using the IE settings window.

Can anybody suggest me how to solve this task for the built-in IE?

---

Some related tools and articles I've managed to find:

1. The [Script-blocking in Internet Explorer](https://safebrowsering.wordpress.com/2012/09/25/script-blocking-in-internet-explorer/) article.
2. The QuickSet Internet Zone tool by TeraByte Unlimited. Can be downloaded from [this page](http://www.terabyteunlimited.com/downloads-free-software.htm). Found it on the Wilders Security Forums [here](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/using-ie-feature-to-get-noscript-like-functionality.349649/).

Answer (score 1):

it is possible in win7 to change this setting with batch script.

disable:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3" /t REG_DWORD /v 1400 /d 3 /f
```

enable:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3" /t REG_DWORD /v 1400 /d 0 /f
```

please note that there is no way to refresh internet options with ie open
except thru the internet options gui. for this reason, you will be best
served by closing ie, running the script, then opening ie.

if you wish to retain your open pages, the technique in win7 would be
to use a batch script after this fashion:

```
taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe

reg add(etc)

start "" "program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

please note the syntax in the start statement:

```
quote quote space quote path quote
```

specifying a verbatim literal in the start statement is necessary when
the folder names contain spaces.

since you are killing ie, it should reopen saying "your last session
ended unexpectedly" with an option to "restore last session".

if win8 has changed its operation enough, the above will not work,
but hopefully, this will give you enough to find an analogous
solution.

Comment: It is not exactly what I needed. My main requirements: (1) an interactive tool I can use in IE without reopening the browser and (2) the ability to disable scripts only for SOME sites. However, thank you for your suggestion.